# Importing CSV data with nullable DateTime values C#

Tags: c#, csv, nullable

I'm attempting to import a CSV file into a List in my code and initially, this was working fine, but I now need to modify this to allow null values for some of the DateTime fields (csvStartTime and csvEndTime).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

private List<ColorDays> csvData;

csvData = new List<ColorDays>();

public List<T> GetData<T>(string file)
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            var lines = GetCSVLines(file);
            var headerLine = lines.First();
            var columnNames = headerLine.Split(',');
            var rows = lines.Skip(1);

            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            rows.ToList().ForEach(r =>
            {
                var cells = r.Split(',');
                T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    var prop = properties
                    .SingleOrDefault(p =>p.Name == columnName);
                    Type propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
                    var value = cells[index++];
                    prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            });

            return list;
        }

        public List<string> GetCSVLines(string file)
        {
            return File.ReadLines(file).ToList();
        }

        public class ColorDays
        {
            public DateTime csvDate { get; set; } //DT
            public string csvWeekColor { get; set; }
            public string csvDayColor { get; set; }
            public string csvWeekDay { get; set; }
            public string csvAorB { get; set; }
            public DateTime csvStartTime { get; set; } //DT
            public DateTime csvEndTime { get; set; } //DT
            public string csvDirection { get; set; }
        }
```

If I change the ColorDays class to nullable DateTime the parse fails.

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to
> 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX]]'.

I'm pretty new to parsing data and struggling to get my head around how to get this working.  I was reading about using CsvHelper but I'm limited to what I can easily package up and followed this video which is where I got my current solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsQ4hYw1TMQ

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "the parse fails"  You are doing the parsing, so perhaps you could elaborate with more detail.

Comment: Side note: Parsing CSV is not a simple task as it might appear to be. Don't try to reinvent the wheel and use one of the existing CSV parsing libraries.

Comment: Updated with the error message

Comment: The net library will not parse a Null DateTime.  You need to add a test in the foreach when type is DateTime and CSV data is an empty string the you do not parse.  If you need a value in the DateTime put either DateTime.Now or put the default value new DateTime.